# Oracle Apex: Is it possible to set HTML as item value in checkbox group?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an checkbox item that gets values from table, I want to display part of text as a subtext like in this example:
[checkbox values in format I want it to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYwaO.png)

Is it possible to do this using HTML or in any other way?
Thank you

I tried to send value in pure HTML format but it just displays HTML elements as text in application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to achieve your requirement.

- Create Page Item of type "checkbox group"
- Use "SQL Query" as source for the List Of Values:
  Source:

```
SELECT 'Large Text<br><span style="font-size:16px">this is large text</span>', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Large Text<br><span style="font-size:10px">this is small text</span>', 2 FROM DUAL
```

- Uncheck the attribute "Security > Escape special characters"

This gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: This is what I was missing (Escape special characters). Thank you